# Angularjs ng-class='active' not making selected category active

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to active category name which user selects but its not getting highlighted.Where i am going wrong please help.

Index.jsp

```
 <ul class="nav" ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl">

                        <li ng-class="{ selCategory == ''}"><a href="#!/home"><i class="icon bb-bars"></i>All Category</a></li>

                         <li data-ng-class="{'active' : selCategory == '/{{category.name}}'}" ng-repeat="category in categories | limitTo:10:10">
                         <a href="#!/blogs/{{category.name}}/latest"><i class="{{iconsList[$index].name}}"></i>{{ category.name }}</a>
                          </li>

                       <li>
</ul>
```

in index page i was displaying all categories name.once user selects it has to be highlighted .data-ng-class='active' not working

Comment: did you take a look at the value of `selCategory == '/{{category.name}}'`

Comment: yes its displaying name which we select

Comment: I mean did you take a look at theresult of the expression, it either should be true or false.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot i took selCategory == true

Answer (score 1):

I solved  this with help of this link . .http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/angular-js-add-class-to-active-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as

```
<li data-ng-class="{'active' : (selCategory == category.name)}" ng-repeat="category in categories | limitTo:10:10">
```

Comment: is **selCategory** and **category.name** defined in your controller?